# Error with node-sass when I use the latest node:stretch docker image

Tags: node.js, docker, node-sass

Starting from today, my builds started failing with errors related with node-sass.

After some research, I found the docker image was trying to find some binding.node that doesn't exist in the node-sass GitHub repository.

After a lot of failures, I realized the docker image I was using, was node:stretch and this image was updated 13 hours ago.

I tried to change to the previous version, node:11.14.0-stretch and the error is gone.

I know I fixed the problem for now, but was this the right procedure? Was there anything else I could do?

Comment: I recommend always using an explicit version instead of `latest` tag. This would make sure that you'll have no more surprises in the future.

Comment: I know that, but this was an heritage from other team...

Comment: Then I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[node-sass 4.12 has been released with support for Node 12](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.12.0). Because it is a binary module, it needs to recompile new bindings when new releases of Node are released. Pinning to "latest" or a non-specified version of the image can cause this to happen with a new Node release is made (which you figured out by re-pinning to a particular version).